# Applications of Numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, applications

I'm in a course of Numerical Methods and part of an assignment is find an article about an application of numerical methods, explain this article and present a program (in matlab/octave) that reproduce the proces in the article.

I'm not qualified to talk about something very complicated physics or biology (for example), then, I'm looking for an article that talks about some numerical method but that is not "too complicated" about science to which it applies.

I was thinking some article about Quasi Newton methods maybe applied to Physics, for example I found [this](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~keyes/papers/jfnk.pdf), I was also reviewing "The Mathematics of Numerical Analysis" of AMS-SIAM Summer Seminar in Appied Mathematics, 1995, but I want to cosider anothers.

My course of Numerical Methods is about Numerical Algebra, Intepolation, Optimization and Differential equations.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: to clarify, are you interested in linear algebra numerical methods (not related to differential equations)?

Comment: I would suggest looking into topics in mathematical finance

Comment: @Alex R., linear algebra related to differential equations could be nice :)
I'm looking for specific articles. Thanks.

Comment: This feature [article](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-pagerank) shows a pretty simple example of Google Pagerank, it essentially boils down to a few lines of code to implement the power method, but the construction is interesting to make this numerically fast given the enormous size of the internet.

Comment: @JessicaK, thanks! :)